# Weird WPF alignment in grid

Tags: .net, wpf, layout

I'm trying to draw a filled ellipse inside an empty ellipse (like a radiobutton), the whole thing being scalable.

I've tried this way (the grid looks necessary, if I use a border the proportions won't look the same)

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

When the control is 30x30, the filled ellipse doesn't look centered, there's a small offset (looks like it's nearer from the lower-right corner).
If I change 2-5-2 to 1-2-1, it looks nearer from the upper-left corner.

Any idea of why it's behaving this way ? And more important, how can I truly give it a more symmetrical look ?

Thank you in advance (and sorry for my bad english) for any help. (BTW, I'm using .Net FW 4.5)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, this is because of the measurements you have. You've said the control should be 30x30, but then you've split that up in a way that makes it impossible to evenly distribute: 50% to the middle column (15 pixels) leaves 15 pixels to be evenly distributed between the other two columns, which can't be evenly done.

My suggestion is setting the measurements to something friendlier, such as 32x32 (which seems to work fine when I try it and is the typical approach) - but if you need it to be truly scalable to any size, perhaps set some properties to let your objects ignore the "rounding" that WPF does when elements are between pixels, here are my suggestions:

[MSDN UseLayoutRounding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/27/layout-rounding.aspx)

[MSDN PixelSnapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908(v=vs.85).aspx)

Try setting these on the grid and ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the RowDefinitions height and width from 2 to 3 and that seemed to do the job.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Seems to fix that problem but probably not a good fix if you are going to use a bigger than 30x30 control